# Send email with attachment with the loopback email datasource

Tags: loopbackjs, nodemailer

Is it possible to send an attachment with the loopback email datasource?

All I can see in the source documentation are these fields:

- @property {String} to Email addressee.  Required.
- @property {String} from Email sender address.  Required.
- @property {String} subject Email subject string.  Required.
- @property {String} text Text body of email.
- @property {String} html HTML body of email.

Comment: I believe this question should be left open, as it's not a duplicate in this context, it's clear what the author is asking, it is on topic and not too broad or opinion based.

Comment: people just automatically mark questions down now.  it's got ridiculous

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Email-connector.html):

> **Nodemailer: Where to Find Documentation**
>
> The email connector is
>   essentially a LoopBack-integrated interface to the [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) library.
>   This page gives a usage example; for full documentation of
>   configuration options, refer to the [nodemailer documention](https://nodemailer.com/).

[Here's where nodemailer have documented attachments.](https://nodemailer.com/using-attachments/)

Here's an example of different types of attachments in the context of loopback:

```
app.models.Email.send({
  to: 'example@example.com',
  from: 'no-reply@example.com',
  subject: 'Email Subject',
  html: '<b>Hello</b>',
  attachments: [
    {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
      filename: 'text1.txt',
      content: 'hello world!'
    },
    {   // binary buffer as an attachment
      filename: 'text2.txt',
      content: new Buffer('hello world!','utf-8')
    },
    {   // file on disk as an attachment
      filename: 'text3.txt',
      path: '/path/to/file.txt' // stream this file
    },
    {   // filename and content type is derived from path
      path: '/path/to/file.txt'
    },
    {   // stream as an attachment
      filename: 'text4.txt',
      content: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
    },
    {   // define custom content type for the attachment
      filename: 'text.bin',
      content: 'hello world!',
      contentType: 'text/plain'
    },
    {   // use URL as an attachment
      filename: 'license.txt',
      path: 'https://raw.github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/master/LICENSE'
    },
    {   // encoded string as an attachment
      filename: 'text1.txt',
      content: 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQh',
      encoding: 'base64'
    },
    {   // data uri as an attachment
      path: 'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
    },
    {
      // use pregenerated MIME node
      raw: 'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        'Hello world!'
    }
  ],
}, err => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there any full sample code  for mail sending, because even i am trying to send an email after the form submits.

Comment: Do i need to install the nodemailer seperately for sending emails through loopback

Comment: I believe it's installed by loopback as part of it's email connector.

Comment: I am also trying to send an email with attachment but its not working, data is one module and the attachment is in another module am trying combine and send it through email. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451895/loopback-send-email-with-attachment-from-another-module